# Bootstrap modal form doesn't show content

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Following is my modal form

```
<div id="editModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="editModalLabel">Detailed View</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Role Name : 
                        <asp:Label ID="lblRoleName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                </table>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and I'm calling it like below on button click

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
sb.Append(@"<script type='text/javascript'>");
sb.Append("$('#editModal').modal('show');");
sb.Append(@"</script>");
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "EditModalScript", sb.ToString(), false);
```

The problem is it doesn't show the content of the modal form. But an empty form gets loaded when I click the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed `class="modal hide fade"` to `class="modal fade"`